# How to create Composite object without parent?

Tags: java, swt

I'm writing a project in Java using SWT. I would like to create a temporary container for some controls.

How would I create a composite control without a parent object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, a Composite is a widget and needs a parent, but you can create it on a Shell you will never open(), then use setParent() when you want to display it.

Comment: It is work well. How I get children controls from shell object?

Answer (score 0):

One other option would be to create it in such a way that it cannot be seen, i.e. visible=false and excluded from layout, etc.